# raspberry pi3 with external Bluetooth data receive issue

Tags: android, python-2.7, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

I have developed android app which send data over Bluetooth.I'm using raspberry to receive data.I have connected HC05 Bluetooth module to raspberry pi3 GPIO pins(UART0 Tx ,UART0r Rx,3.3v PWR,GND). I have written Python code to display data.But after some time (After some data received) python showing following error:

```
 File "usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py" line 460 in read
    raise SerialException('device reports readiness to read but returned no data(device disconnected?)')
    serial.serialutil.SerialException:device reports readiness to read but returned no data(device disconnected ?)
```

and disconnected with HC05 and then if I try to send then its showing error

```
File "usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py" line 453 in read 
buf=os.read(self.fd,size-len(read))
 OSError:[Error no 11]Resource Temporarily unavaliable
```

Please anyone help me on this.

```
My python code is as below:
import serial
import time

port=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0",baudrate=9600)

while True:
        rcv = port.read(2)
        print str(rcv)
```

Comment: My python code is as following:

Comment: Ask at the raspberry stack site, there will be more easy to get help: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/